# How do you eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements?

Tags: list, ocaml

(In Ocaml)

This solution works

```
let compress l =
let rec compress_2 l e =
    match l with
        | [] -> [e]
        | h::t -> if (h=e)
                    then (compress_2 t e)
                    else e::(compress_2 t)
in
    match l with
        | [] -> []
        | h::t -> compress_2 t h;;
```

But why doesn't this solution work?

```
let rec compress (l: 'a list) : 'a list =
match l with
    | [] -> []
    | h::[] -> [h]
    | h1::h2::t -> if h1=h2 then h2::(compress t) else h1::h2::(compress t) ;;
```

Comment: regarding your b) solution: Think about the result for [1;2;2]. It would work if you left h2 in the list like 'else h1::compress(h2::t)'

Answer (score 4):

In this case

```
| h1::h2::t -> if h1=h2 then h2::(compress t) else h1::h2::(compress t) ;;
```

You won't notice a duplicate if `h2` is the same as the head of `t`.  You need to
pass `(h2 :: t)` in the recursive calls to `compress`.

I've written this function numerous times (a candidate for the standard List library, maybe).  Here's how I usually write it (avoiding an extra cons or two):

```
let rec compress l =
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | [_] -> l
    | h1 :: ((h2 :: _) as tail) ->
        if h1 = h2 then compress tail else h1 :: compress tail
```

This isn't tail recursive, so it consumes a linear amount of stack space.  This is fine if you know your lists tend to be pretty short.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. Could you briefly explain what "as" means?

Comment: It's a way of giving a name to part of a pattern, so you can refer to it by name in the associated expression.  It's useful in exactly the situation with `compress`: you need to access the same data structure at various levels (some internal parts and some not so internal parts).  It's called an "alias pattern" in the manual: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/patterns.html

Answer (score 1):

ExtLib (and thus Batteries) do have this function -- even with an additional parameter to pass in your own equality-function:
http://nit.gforge.inria.fr/extlib/ExtList.List.html#VALunique

If you want to roll your own, try this:

```
let compress eq ls =
   (* acc: accumulator; x: the optional comparison value; xs: the not-unique list *)
   let rec remdup acc x xs =
    match (x, xs) with
    | (_, []) -> acc
    | (None, y::ys) -> remdup (y::acc) (Some y) ys
    | (Some z, y::ys) -> if eq z y then remdup acc x ys else remdup (y::acc) (Some y) ys
   in
   (* need to reverse the final list as we appended in front of the accumulator *)
   List.rev (remdup [] None ls)
```

and then just

> let unique = compress (=) [1;1;1;2;3;3;4;5;6;6;7;8;9;9;9]